# increasing the page width in oracle reports builder

Tags: oracle, user-interface, oracle10g, report

I am designing a new report using oracle reports builder that comes with 10g. I have many columns to be inserted horizontally. But I couldn't increase the page width of the body section beyond 8.5 inches. But I can see the page width of some existing reports to be more than 16 inches. How do I increase the page width?. I have been googling for an hour but couldn't find anything useful. I have tried tinkering with the settings at,

> File->Page Size
>
> Tools->Options->Margin
>
> Edit->Preferences

but no gain.

So any help would be much welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Object Navigator window, open up the Layout Model node.  Then double-click on the Main Section node to bring up its properties in the Property Palette window.  There you will find Width, which defaults to 8.5, and Height, which defaults to 11.

Answer (score 1):

Tony's answer shows how to adjust the width of the report. If you want to adjust the margin, then open up the Layout Model, click on the button "Edit Margin" (visit the tooltips to identify the button), click on the thick black border and then adjust the margin by dragging the small white square.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I wanted to change the width only. My query was ambiguous, sorry. :)

Answer (score 0):

In `paper layout` go to `headersection` and double click `change width height`.
Do the same for `mainsection` and `trailer section`.