# how to increase paper report width in oracle report builder

Tags: oracle, reportbuilder

I have a query with about 30+ columns and i want the columns header to all appear in 1 row but right now it is displayed in 3 different rows and same goes for the data.

I have tried increasing the width of the report in the Main section,header and even trailer but the change is not being reflected on the paper layout when I run it.

Is there any other way to increase the width?

Thanks in advance for any possible help

Comment: Does this answer your question?

 [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178698/increasing-the-page-width-in-oracle-reports-builder][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178698/increasing-the-page-width-in-oracle-reports-builder

Comment: @vishad unfortunately no. I tried that already but it doesnt seem to work for me.. though i changed the width when i re run the report it still display the default size

Comment: Forgive me if i sound knave, but hope you are also increasing the frame width along with increasing the page size?

Comment: @vishad yes i even increase the margin. Bt when i rerun it seems the changes is not reflected. Bt nvm, I just did the arrangement manually instead of relying on run paper layout to get the right width. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to object navigator.
select main section in the paper layout tab.
double click or right click on the main section to open it's property inspector.
then  select  width and write your desired length (e.g 20)